# Obtain Specific Preferred DNS Server

Tags: windows, networking, dns

Is there a way to obtain specific Preferred DNS server, say for example 192.168.0.3 when I tick "Obtain DNS Server Automatically"?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Um, what's the difference from just setting it manually?

Comment: I can assign specific IP address for client computers if they choose to obtain IP address automatically...so I wonder if it is also possible to assign Preferred DNS when they choose to obtain it automatically.

Comment: You mean via DHCP? Depends on your DHCP server, but usually yes. It's configured at the same server, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like IP addresses, the 'automatic' DNS servers are provided by your DHCP server. Normal DHCP servers (e.g. ISC dhcpd) allow those to be configured, both globally and per-client, but home "wireless routers" usually don't, so it depends on what you're using for your LAN.